# PhoneGap "git" command line tool is not installed

Tags: iphone, ios, git, cordova, command-line-interface

I'm using Phonegap 3.0 and the Command Line Interface as per the phonegap website install instructions.
I have created an app just fine on iOS:

`npm install -g phonegap`
...

`phonegap create Test -n Test` (creates an app named "Test" and located in "Test" folder)

`phonegap build ios`
then...

`phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git` 
Which responds with this error:

**`Error fetching plugin: Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH.`**

Now, I have tried installing the "git" command line tool, but I'm not exactly sure if I'm installing it right, or if I was even downloading the right thing, or how to align the PATH to be accessible.

Any advice here? Has anyone dealt with or seen this? Thank you very much

Comment: How did you install git?  If you run `which git` in a terminal what doe sit say?

Comment: Assuming your developing on a Mac, make sure Xcode is installed, then `Preferences... -> Downloads -> Command Line Tools`. If you're not on a Mac, have fun/good luck developing for iOS, and please mention your OS/distro.

Comment: Try my answer it will work both in mac and windows...

Answer (score 6):

Hi "git" is also a node module. Simplest way want i found is.

```
npm install -g git
```

This will install git in you node source location as a module.

Restart the machine.

Install phonegap plugin:

```
C:\Users\user1\yourprojectname>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

You will get response as:

```
Fetching plugin from "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-cam
            era.git"...
Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.camera" for android
Preparing android project org.apache.cordova.camera installed on android.
```

Hope this will be very helpful. If any issue reply.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the git CLI tool for Mac:

http://git-scm.com/download/mac

Answer (score 1):

Download and install git from http://git-scm.com/downloads . Set path in System Environment variable pointing to the installation path, in my case C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin.

So go to control panel-> system ->Advance System Settings -> Environment Variable -> System Variable

Select Path and Edit it. Append C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin to it.

It will work for sure.

Comment: I used cmd:> npm install -g git. then, It's Working for Win 7 64-bit. I did n't restart my PC. Before this command, I have full Cordova 3.6.0 set up configured.